# Changing an element in an array of structs changes every element

Tags: arrays, c, struct

I'm trying to change variables of structs in an array, but for some reason when I change one the rest also change, code is below. I've tried using -> and (*logEntries[i]), but neither work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct logEntry{
    char *name;
    struct tm * time;
    int code;
}logEntry;

char *readline(){
    int lineSize = 100;
    int counter = 0;
    int active = 1;
    char *currLine = malloc(sizeof(char)*lineSize);    
    char c;
    
    while (active == 1){
     c = getchar();
     
     if (c == EOF || c == '\n'){
         currLine[counter] = '\0';
         return currLine;
     }
     else{
         currLine[counter] = c;
         counter++;
     }
     
     if(counter > lineSize){
         lineSize += 100;
         currLine = realloc(currLine, lineSize*sizeof(char));
     }
    }
}

char **SeparateTokens(char *line){
    int counter = 0;
    int lineLength = sizeof(line);
    char **tokens = malloc(lineLength*sizeof(char*));
    char *token;
    
    token = strtok(line, " \t\r\n");
    
    while (token != NULL){
     tokens[counter] = token;
     counter++;
     
     if(counter > lineLength){
         lineLength += 100;
         tokens = realloc(tokens, lineLength*sizeof(char*));
     }
     
     token = strtok(NULL, " \t\r\n=");
    }
    
    tokens[counter] = NULL;
    
    return tokens;
}

int Execute(char **args,struct logEntry *logEntries, int logCount){    
         for(int i = 0; i < logCount; i++){
             printf("%s\t%s\t%d\n",strtok(asctime(logEntries[i].time), "\n"), logEntries[i].name, logEntries[i].code);
         }
         return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    int active = 1;
    char *line;
    char **args;
    logEntry* logEntries = malloc(100*sizeof(logEntry));
    int logLength = 100;
    int logEntriesCounter = 0;
    time_t timeInSeconds;
    int status;
    
    while(active == 1){
     line = readline();
     args = SeparateTokens(line);
     status = Execute(args, logEntries, logEntriesCounter);
     if(status == 1){
         time(&timeInSeconds);
         logEntries[logEntriesCounter].name = args[0];
         logEntries[logEntriesCounter].time = localtime(&timeInSeconds);
         logEntries[logEntriesCounter].code = status;
         logEntriesCounter++;
         if(logEntriesCounter > logLength){
             logLength += 100;
             logEntries = realloc(logEntries, logLength*sizeof(logEntry));
         }
     }       
     free(line);
     free(args);    
    }
}
```

The pointers for args are freed at the end of each command execution, I don't believe the value of logEntriesCounter is going to a NULL or negative value at the end of each loop, as the only modification is a ++. The log command should print out the history of every command used, with a time and a return code, based on my output results, every element is being changed.

Comment: Your code does not compile. You have a stray `else` and a number of undeclared variables.

Comment: *when I change one the rest also change*. What does that mean exactly? Please give the exact expected result vs actual result.

Comment: @Schwern, the code depends on another 100ish lines, but stackoverflow limits the length  of my code.
@.kaylum Basically, when I change logEntries[logEntriesCounter].name, it should only change the name for the element at logEntriesCounter, instead it seems to change it for every element before it as well.

Comment: @ch4se We can't help you if we can't reproduce the problem. Try to cut it down to the smallest possible *working* code which demonstrates the problem. In doing so you might also find the problem.

Comment: I would speculate that you are not allocating any buffers to the fields of your `logEntries` but assigning them with the same pointer. But without [mcve] it will remain a speculation.

Comment: *instead it seems to change it for every element before it as well*. How are you determining that? We need the exact code that shows that. Describing things in words is usually not clear enough - exact code is the best. As currently shown `logEntriesCounter` is never incremented. In short, your code is too incomplete for us to understand and answer the question. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Any change the `logEntriesCounter` is negative or outside the bounds of the array when the bad write occurs?

Comment: I would also ask if you are ever allocating memory within your struct for `*name` - if you just `strcpy()` to the location without allocating memory, you would see this sort of behavior as well.  Copying the address (not a string copy) of a const string would probably be ok though for name.

Comment: I need to see `separateTokens()` to be sure but I think it is returning a pointer to a variable local to `separateTokens()`.  So `args[0]` is always the same spot in memory and since `logEntries[logEntriesCounter].name` is a pointer to memory when that memory changes everything points to the changed data.  Make sure `separateTokens()` is not returning a pointer to a local variable.  Can you post the code for that function?

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, I've made some modifications to the post and it should compile now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localtime` reuses the same memory to return its result. When you call `localtime` multiple times you're overwriting the previous result. If you check the address of `logEntries[logEntriesCounter].time` you'll find that each entry points at the same memory.

We can demonstrate that here.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    struct tm* times[3];

    for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        time_t t = time(NULL) + 1000 * i;
    
        // localtime returns the same memory each time
        times[i] = localtime(&t);
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        printf("%d - %p - %s", i, (void *)times[i], asctime(times[i]));
    }
}

// 0 - 0x7f9c60c05ae0 - Wed Feb 17 16:47:17 2021
// 1 - 0x7f9c60c05ae0 - Wed Feb 17 16:47:17 2021
// 2 - 0x7f9c60c05ae0 - Wed Feb 17 16:47:17 2021
```

Each element contains the same pointer and date. All three elements of `times` point at the same memory. Each call to `localtime` overwrites that shared memory.

Most of time.h suffers from this problem. To avoid this, use the _r variants like localtime_r and asctime_r. r for ["reentrant"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing)). These require that you allocate the memory for their result.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    struct tm* times[3];

    for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        time_t t = time(NULL) + 1000 * i;

        // Allocate memory for the result.
        // Can't use stack memory, that's local to each iteration of the loop.
        struct tm *ltime = malloc(sizeof(struct tm));
        times[i] = localtime_r(&t, ltime);
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        // Allocate a buffer for asctime_r.
        // Since we're not storing it, it's safe to reuse the buffer.
        char buf[26];
        printf("%d - %p - %s", i, (void *)times[i], asctime_r(times[i], buf));
    }

    // And be sure to free the allocated memory.
    for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        free(times[i]);
    }

}

// 0 - 0x7ff3b3c05ae0 - Wed Feb 17 16:14:36 2021
// 1 - 0x7ff3b3e04330 - Wed Feb 17 16:31:16 2021
// 2 - 0x7ff3b3e04370 - Wed Feb 17 16:47:56 2021
```

Alternatively, don't store the `struct tm` as a pointer. Then the return value from localtime will be copied to the struct.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    struct tm times[3];

    for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        time_t t = time(NULL) + 1000 * i;
        // The return value is copied.
        times[i] = *localtime(&t);
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        printf("%d - %p - %s", i, (void *)&times[i], asctime(&times[i]));
    }
}

// 0 - 0x7ffeedba02b0 - Wed Feb 17 16:15:24 2021
// 1 - 0x7ffeedba02e8 - Wed Feb 17 16:32:04 2021
// 2 - 0x7ffeedba0320 - Wed Feb 17 16:48:44 2021
```

Getting used to using the _r variants and working with pointers is better in the long run.